# New Ember app gives blank screen

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to ember and doing a [introductory tutorial](https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/getting-started-with-ember-cli-3dd0a4022415#.4q1tyocpl) to build a simple app. When I create a new app and start server, I try visiting the localhost page (http://localhost:4200/) in my browser but the page is blank. The browser window title is of my app name but there is no "Welcome to Ember" text as their should be. Also the ember inspector says "Ember application not detected!" although the little ember icon appears in the address bar of Firefox indicating that there is an ember app.

I have tried to restart the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/getting-started-with-ember-cli-3dd0a4022415#.4q1tyocpl) 3 times now and come up with same results. I have followed all set-up steps provided [here](https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/getting-started-with-ember-cli-3dd0a4022415#.ciu6ri8db). The only thing I did different or in addition to the turorial is I had to run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`because of [permissions issues](https://ar.al/scribbles/npm-install-g-please-try-running-this-command-again-as-root-administrator/).

All I have done so far is install node, npm, bower, ember-cli 2.2.0-beta.2., and then run these few commands:

```
ember new ember2-blog
cd ember2-blog
ember server
```

The terminal gives me a "Build successful - 7016ms." message but I go to http://localhost:4200/ and see the blank page... The inspector says "no ember app detected". Seems like I'm missing something simple but can't figure it out. Is it something to do with permissions? Please and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug due to a new version of jQuery. For now you can change the following line in your `bower.json` file. Then run `bower install` and it should work.

```
"jquery": "^1.11.3",
```

to

```
"jquery": "1.11.3",
```

A new version of ember.js is [imminent](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/12793) which should fix [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5316).