# Emberjs.com website beginner Tutorial

Tags: ember.js

I will start by saying I am new to Ember. I am starting to wrap my mind around the concepts but I haven't been able to make it work...

I tried following the basic tutorial on the emberjs.com website:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/tutorial/routes-and-templates/

As far as I can tell I have everything installed/updated properly, and I understand what is supposed to happen...but when I run the server via the "ember server" command my templates do not load. The index.html page is being picked up, but anything I put in my templates (including the application.hbs) is missing.

Any ideas?? I really want to get into Ember, but I can't get past page one of any tutorial I try because of this issue. Please help! :)

Comment: Can you add your project to github so we can see it? Odds are you forgot an `{{outlet}}` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Ember app gives blank screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702746/new-ember-app-gives-blank-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be facing a recent ember-cli bug (which is fixed by [Ember CLI 1.13.14](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v1.13.14) - released a few hours ago.). [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702746/new-ember-app-gives-blank-screen) people have [encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1) that issue recently.

For reference, the fix (if you're not updating ember-cli) is (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702746/new-ember-app-gives-blank-screen) by [Lawree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761877/lawree))

> This is a bug due to a new version of jQuery. For now you can change
>   the following line in your bower.json file. Then run bower install and
>   it should work.
>
> ```
> "jquery": "^1.11.3", to
>
> "jquery": "1.11.3",
> ```

Comment: Nice catch! Voting to close as dupe.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up reinstalling ember and it now works so that was probably it :)