# Ember-cli upgrade broke everything

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I had a running Ember program built using Ember-Cli 1.13.12 using Node 4.2.4.  I tried to upgrade to Ember-Cli 2.3.0 running on Node 4.2.6.  I followed the procedure outlined in: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases.  After the upgrade, my program generated all sorts of errors.  I spent an entire day trying to get the program to work but couldn't.  So I decided to try reverting back to Ember-cli 1.13.12.  I checked out the lastest working version of my program before the upgrade attempt using git.  I did the following to revert back to Ember-cli 1.13.12:

```
  npm uninstall -g ember-cli
  npm cache clean
  bower cache clean
  npm install -g ember-cli@1.13.12

  rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp
  npm install
  bower install
```

But the system still doesn't work.  'Ember Server' works as expected.  But  when I go to localhost:4200 in my browser, I get two errors:

```
 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1
 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `tw/app`
```

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being hit by the problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738389/emberjs-com-website-beginner-tutorial/34739239#34739239).

You can probably fix the issue by upgrading to ember-cli 1.13.14, if not check bellow.

For reference, the fix (if you're not updating ember-cli) is (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702746/new-ember-app-gives-blank-screen) by [Lawree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761877/lawree))

> This is a bug due to a new version of jQuery. For now you can change
>   the following line in your bower.json file. Then run bower install and
>   it should work.
>
> "jquery": "^1.11.3", to
>
> "jquery": "1.11.3",

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.  Everything works as before.

I'm going to save down everything and make another attempt to   upgrade to Ember-cli 2.3.0 beta.  Wish the Ember-cli team would make upgrading a bit easier.  When you do an 'ember init' and differences are identified, something it's difficult to one way or another when differences identified are in ember-cli-generated files.`

Comment: Yeah  upgrading sometimes comes with some pain, but I believe they are working hard to make things smoother for everyone. It's getting better.

Comment: Biggest problem is making the wrong decision on what to do when there are changes with the Ember-cli generated code.  Seems to me the upgrade process can be modified to handle that automatically.